# Hook for Adding Custom Channel Entries Parameter Option

Tags: channel-entries, add-on-development, parameters

I'm trying to do something like orderby="custom_order"

What hook would let you add and run a custom parameter option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A hook would probably not be the best way to do this. With a module, you can extend the functionality of the channel:entries tag by passing your custom module tag off to channel:entries.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/airways/1322600) is an excellent example to follow.

Basically you'd have to use the parameters sent to your custom module to create a pipe-separated list of entry ids that you want in the order you want them. Then you'd feed it to the channel entries tag by using `$this->EE->TMPL->tagparams['fixed_order'] = $entry_ids;`

Extending the channel:entries tag like this makes it act exactly like a normal version of the tag, so all the parsing works perfectly, etc.